# I don't understand how "Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined" works

Tags: javascript

I just started learning JS and I understand that if I use a variable outside its scope it is an Uncaught reference.

I have a function called `addTask()` which gets called when I click on the Add Task Button. There is only one reference to this function, and that's the function itself(I haven't used it anywhere else).
Everything worked, then I added a delete task button and it stopped working.

## Edit

I found a typo in the `deleteTask()` function while writing this question, and removing it solved the issue.

I still do not understand why it caused a problem with `addTask()`.

Here's my HTML.

```html
<h2>ToDo</h2>
<div class="task-control">
  <input type="text" id="textbox" placeholder="Tasks here" />
  <input type="date" name="" id="datepicker" />
  <button id="add-button" onclick="addTask()">Add Task</button>
  <span id="space">&#124</span>
  <button id="clear-list" onclick="clearList()">Clear List</button>
</div>
<hr />
<div id="todo-list"></div>
```

And here's the JavaScript

```js
const taskList = [];
const taskListInPage = document.getElementById("todo-list");
renderTasks();

function renderTasks() {
  taskListInPage.innerHTML = "";
  taskList.forEach(function(taskInList) {
    const taskItem = document.createElement("div");
    taskItem.innerText = taskInList.title + " " + taskInList.dueDate;

    const deleteButton = document.createElement("button");
    deleteButton.innerHTML = "&#128465";
    deleteButton.style = "margin-left:12px";
    deleteButton.id = taskInList.id;
    deleteButton.onclick = deleteTask;
    taskItem.appendChild(deleteButton);

    taskListInPage.appendChild(taskItem);
  });
}

function addTask() {
  const textboxInPage = document.getElementById("textbox");
  const title = textboxInPage.value;

  const datePicker = document.getElementById("datepicker");
  const dueDate = datePicker.value;

  const taskId = new Date().getTime();

  taskList.push({
    title: title,
    dueDate: dueDate,
    id: taskId
  });
  renderTasks();
}

function clearList() {
  taskList.splice(0, taskList.length);
  renderTasks();
}

function deleteTask(event) {
  const deleteButtonIP = event.target;
  cosnt idToDelete = deleteButtonIP.id;
}
```

This is the error message

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: addTask is not defined
```

Comment: `addTask` calls `renderTasks` which references `deleteTask`. So if `deleteTask` had a typo, then `addTask` won't work as `renderTasks` will throw an error when `addTask` calls it. Maybe that was your issue?

Comment: You need to read up on delegation. Make sure your IDs are unique. Give the delete button a class and have it delete the closest div

Comment: You still have a typo, it's `const idToDelete = deleteButtonIP.id;` not `cosnt idToDelete = deleteButtonIP.id;`

Comment: Can you paste the error message in your question?

Comment: @mplungjan that's new info, will read up on that, sounds like a nice way to make it simpler

Comment: @NickParsons Thanks for the clarification, I did not realize that a function being referenced can cause an error without even being called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

addTask is not a problem here.
and in deleteTask, you can use this code to delete the desired task.

```
  function deleteTask(event) {
  const taskIndex = taskList.findIndex(function(task){
    return task.id === event.target.id
  });

  taskList.splice(taskIndex , 1);
  renderTasks();
}
```

here, first it finds the desired task and then deletes it.